# Php security question about post validation

Tags: php, security

Is the following a valid way to validate some info coming from a post?

```
function validate($age, $name, $sex) {
    $pdo = new PDO(...);
    $age = (int)$age;
    $name = $pdo -> quote($name);
    $sex = (strtolower($sex) == "m" ? "m" : "f");

    // and then process data with pdo's query method.
}
```

Do you see any security flaw in this function? If yes, can you help me to fix them?

Comment: It's valid in sense that it won't cause SQL injections, but your usage of PDO isn't the best, you should use prepared statements and bind values to their respective types rather than using pdo->quote manually.

Comment: I've read that pdo's prepare function is best only when you repeat a query. So basically, if I escape properly I see no harm in using pdo's query method. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're not wrong, however you can automate the process of passing arguments that are to be escaped properly. For example, you have `int` coercing operation for `$age` and you're manually escaping `$name`. It's small number of variables but what happens when you've got, say 100 variables coming from $_POST? You can write a function that'll take those, and you can force PDO to coerce them to their respective types without the need to do it manually yourself. Anyway, your data's safe and if you prefer to do type coercing manually - you're safe.

Comment: @N.B. thank you, I got the point :) If you provide an answer I'll select your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Escaping/Encoding is not Validation.

Comment: @Shaokan I don't really think my comment is appropriate answer so let's leave it like this :) also, haker has a good point. Escaping isn't really validation. Your data is safe to go in the database. But who says it won't cause relation corruption?

Comment: Well, that's my bad sorry. I actually meant security when I said validation. I, of course, validate my post by checking the length of strings, whether the email is proper or not, or say age is not more than 120 etc etc... I just meant security in this post.

Comment: Take validation and PDO apart into separate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's totally valid and secure as you won't receive any SQL Injections. Btw, if you will repeat the query, rather than `pdo->query` go for prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite.
That's pretty common mistake among PHP users.
Here is a rule you are breaking in your code:

## Do not mix data validation with sql security.

Data validation is one matter and sql security is another.
Data validation rules may change. Sql security rules shouldn't.

Although your current code is safe, the very idea of asking such a question is wrong.
You have to use sql protection techniques **unconditionally**, despite of the data source and contents. That's the only way to be sure.

Besides that, there is just no point in creating different rules for the different fields.
Just run your validation and after that you have to call just the code like this

```
$db->insert($table,$data);
```

and let the internals do care of the data (knowing nothing of it's safety, validness or whatever else nonsense). Got the point?